# UILabel is character wrapping and not word wrapping correctly

Tags: uilabel, uistoryboard, autoshrink

I have a UITextLabel which isn't very wide. I want to display the text "Average Score" With "Average" on the top line and "Score" on the bottom line. But instead, I am getting

```
Averag
e Score
```

What I would like to happen is for the code to automatically adjust the font scale to fit it correctly, but that's not happening.

[image: screen shot of attributes inspector showing min font scale set to 0.5]

Comment: May be Because your label doesn't have width to fit the text "Average"

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was alluding to. But I do have a min font scale set, so I would think that it would scale the font down enough to fit the word. Is there any way to force this?

Comment: AFIK minimum font scale works with `numberOfLines = 1` only. Not sure about this :/

Comment: I think you're right! Dang, that's too bad.